# In wpf when my system is shut down or internet connection gone i need to update a flag to false to database using wcf service

Tags: wpf

In my wpf application when user login i will update Islogin=true when user is logout im updating Islogin=false when my system is crashed or shut down or internet connection gone then this case how to handle,im using wcf service for this

Comment: If your system is crashed it is impossible to change the GUI...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if the network is up then use:

```
bool networkUp
    = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
```

To identify that the system is crashed/shutting down handle the `SystemEvents.SessionEnded` Event. Occurs when the user is logging off or shutting down the system.

Source : MSDN(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionended.aspx)

Just check the status of these and set your `Islogin=false` appropriately.

Comment: Two clients are there client A and client B.First client A is logged in with user name 'Harish' so im updating my status in database to IsLogin=true.If close the wpf application then im Making Islogout=false.When my internet connection is down or system got shutdown then how to update my server database that IsLogin=false so client B can use same credentials

Comment: Network issue you cannot know from client. If you're using a WCF service, `ICommunicationObject.State` will only tell you that a channel between the client and the server is "faulted", if a previous operation resulted in an error and that error wasn't properly handled on the server. And system crash or shutdown event you can fire from client itself.